# how to convert char * to TMemorystream * type?

Tags: c++

1.how to save char * to a image file?
2.how to convert  char * to TMemorystream *  type?

```
void process(char* data, int length)
{
   //the data is a image
}

//I have try follow code,but display a blank photo.
TMemoryStream * MemoryImageStream=new TMemoryStream;
MemoryImageStream->Position=0;
MemoryImageStream->Write(photo,len);
```

Comment: What about `MemoryImageStream->Write(data,length);`? Note you don't really want to _'convert'_ the types here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the appropriate size to the TMemoryImageStream object.

Instead of:

```
TMemoryStream * MemoryImageStream=new TMemoryStream;
    MemoryImageStream-&gt;Position=0;
    MemoryImageStream-&gt;Write(photo,len);
```

change it to:

```
TMemoryStream * MemoryImageStream=new TMemoryStream(len);
    MemoryImageStream-&gt;Position=0;
    MemoryImageStream-&gt;Write(photo,len);
```

See also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1[^]